# ASP.NET PowerShell scripts don't run

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell

I write the script directly.(Import-Module ActiveDirectory). It does not work.

Error Message:

```
(Failed to generate proxies for remote module 'ActiveDirectory'. Files cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. Provide a valid certificate with which to sign the files).
```

Please, tell me the solution.

Also I've tried to execute the command `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` in both cmd 32 and cmd 64.

```
var shell = PowerShell.Create();
shell.Commands.AddScript("New-Item -Path 'C:\\Distrib\\file.txt' -ItemType 'File'");
```

This script works:

```
(PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{powerShellInstance.AddCommand(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + \\Powershell\\test.ps1");
```

`test.ps1` does not work:

```
(New-Item -Path 'C:\\Distrib\\file.txt' -ItemType 'File')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a PowerShell code issue. It is an environment setting.

If you are doing this in an enterprise, then your org has set the policy in your machine for a reason.

Though what JPBlanc would work, unless you have the ability to change this setting by your org admins at the machine level, then you can't change it anyway. You can change it for your user or process level. There are several levels to set for EP and this is well documented.

> [Set-ExecutionPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7)

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy
   [-ExecutionPolicy] <ExecutionPolicy>
   [[-Scope] <ExecutionPolicyScope>]
   [-Force]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser    RemoteSigned
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

There is little to no reason to ever use unrestricted for day to day PowerShell use case, especially at the machine level. I always recommend CurrentUser or Process.

So, create a new Powershell shortcut to startup using the CurrentUser or Proces scope using the RemoteSigned (which is the current default in Windows 10 even at the machine level).

Even when calling this thru code, use the CurrentUser or Process scope and RemoteSigned.

Comment: i did it, My policy is MachinePolicy - Unrestricted, UsesPolicy - Unrestricted, Proccess - Undefined, CurrentUser - Undefined, LocalMachine - Unrestricted.
My scripts don't work.